# DbgView gives error: The file dbgview.sys is already in use

Tags: windows, drivers, debugger

I am trying to debug some driver code using **Dbgview**, first time when I open it it runs fine. But when I close it and restart the **Dbgview** it just gives above error and I can't use  the kernel debugger option of it.

Now I have only one way that is to reboot the system then only it will let me allow to use the kernel debugger.

Is there any other thing I can do rather than just restarting the system every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have just found the another way rather than restarting the os.

All the .sys files are present at `system32`, So what you need to do is, when the error comes just go to `system32` and find the `DbgView.sys` rename it(give any other name than DbgView.sys) and just open `DbgView` and that's it, now you can use the kernel debugger option as well without rebooting the system and the error will not come.

Comment: More exactly: rename `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\Dbgv.sys`